How to Copy and Save Rich Formatted Text with CSS Included for Accurate text
async function saveCopiedText(hasText = "", target, format, useStandardCopy) {
  chrome.storage.local.get(["lastLoggedInUser"], function (result) {
    const lastUserEmail = result.lastLoggedInUser;
    const isSubscribed = userData?.stripeSubscriptionId;
    const userEmail = userData?.email || null;

    // Function to count words in a string, excluding spaces and newlines
    function countWords(text) {
      return text.trim().split(/\s+/).length;
    }

    // Function to truncate text to the first 500 words, preserving spaces and newlines
    function truncateText(text, maxWords) {
      const words = text.trim().split(/\s+/);
      if (words.length <= maxWords) {
        return text;
      }

      let wordCount = 0;
      let index = 0;
      while (wordCount < maxWords && index < text.length) {
        if (!/\s/.test(text[index])) {
          if (index === 0 || /\s/.test(text[index - 1])) {
            wordCount++;
          }
        }
        index++;
      }
      return text.slice(0, index);
    }

    chrome.storage.local.get(
      ["recentlyCopiedItems", "recentlyCopiedLogoutItems"],
      async (result) => {
        let items = userData?.email
          ? result?.recentlyCopiedItems || "[]"
          : result?.recentlyCopiedLogoutItems || "[]";
        items = Array.from(JSON.parse(items));
        const maxItems = userData?.email && isSubscribed ? 15 : 5;

        if (selectedText === "" && !hasText) return;
        const maxWords = isSubscribed ? 5000 : 500;
        let textToCopy = hasText || selectedText;
        let isTextTruncated = false;

        if (countWords(textToCopy) > maxWords) {
          textToCopy = truncateText(textToCopy, maxWords);
          isTextTruncated = true;
          if (!isSubscribed) {
            if (useStandardCopy) {
              renderUpgradePopup(
                `Text has been copied but due to the free tier 500 word limit<br/>only the first 500 words will be saved!<br/><a href="https://www.copyin2clicks.com/premium" target="_blank" style="color:#f59e0b; text-decoration: underline;">✨ Click here to enjoy unlimited copying today! ✨</a>`,
                true
              );
            } else {
              renderUpgradePopup(
                `Free tier in CopyIn2Clicks is limited to 500 words!<br/>Get CopyIn2Clicks Premium now and copy any amount of text effortlessly!<br/><a href="https://www.copyin2clicks.com/premium" target="_blank" style="color:#f59e0b; text-decoration: underline;">✨ Click here to enjoy unlimited copying today! ✨</a>`,
                true
              );

              return;
            }
          } else {
            renderUpgradePopup(
              `Text has been successfully copied to your clipboard, but only the first 5000 words have been saved in the extension!`,
              true
            );
          }
        }

        const newItem = {
          id: new Date().getTime(),
          lastModifiedTimestamp: new Date().getTime(),
          text: textToCopy,
          starred: false,
          email: userEmail,
          isLogout: userData?.message === "Unauthorized" ? true : false,
        };
        items.unshift(newItem);
        console.log("newItem", newItem);

        if (
          items.filter((item) => item.email === userEmail || !item.email)
            .length > maxItems
        ) {
          let unstarredIndex = -1;
          for (let i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (
              (items[i].email === userEmail || !items[i].email) &&
              !items[i].starred
            ) {
              unstarredIndex = i;
              break;
            }
          }
          if (unstarredIndex !== -1) {
            items.splice(unstarredIndex, 1);
          } else {
            items.pop();
          }
        }
        let storageCopyArrayName = "recentlyCopiedLogoutItems";
        if (userData?.email) {
          storageCopyArrayName = "recentlyCopiedItems";
        }
        await chrome.storage.local.set({
          [storageCopyArrayName]: JSON.stringify(items),
        });

        try {
          if ((useStandardCopy && !isSubscribed) || isTextTruncated) {
            console.log("hello , normal copy ");
            // Copy the full text to the clipboard
            await navigator.clipboard.writeText(hasText || selectedText);
          } else if (isSubscribed && format) {
            console.log("hello formatting");
            const selection = window.getSelection();
            const range =
              selection.rangeCount > 0 ? selection.getRangeAt(0) : null;
            const div = document.createElement("div");
            if (range) {
              div.appendChild(range.cloneContents());
            }
            const html = div.innerHTML;
            console.log("Rich Text Copied", html);
             await navigator.clipboard.write([
              new ClipboardItem({
                "text/plain": new Blob([newItem.text], { type: "text/plain" }),
                "text/html": new Blob([html], { type: "text/html" }),
              }),
            ]);
          } else {
            await navigator.clipboard.writeText(newItem.text);
          }
          isSelectionCompleted = true;
          if (!isTextTruncated) {
            setTimeout(() => renderPopup(target), 500);
          }
        } catch (err) {
          renderErrorPopup(
            "Copying is not supported or blocked by the current document"
          );
        }
      }
    );
  });
}

I need to copy rich formatted text such that when pasted into a rich text editor, it retains its exact formatting, including styles. Currently, I'm copying HTML content but not including external CSS or inline styles, which results in the pasted text not appearing as intended.
What I tried: I am currently copying HTML text only, but it does not include the external CSS or other styles.
What I was expecting: I want the copied text to maintain the exact formatting and appearance as it appears in the original source, including all styles.
How can I achieve this? Is there a way to include the CSS styles along with the HTML content to ensure that the pasted text looks exactly the same?

If I understand correctly, the task you wish to achieve isn't easily straightforward because you'd need to inline styles coming from css rules applied to the document. IT would require you to iterate over the computed styles of the elements belonging to the text selection (via window.getComputedStyle) . Waiting for a better answer I may suggest a library doing just that https://github.com/Automattic/juice ... here's a demo https://automattic.github.io/juice/ ...
